# Unable to submit order fulfilment feed amazon mws

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-marketplace

I am trying to update shipping information through the feed API and here is my xml feed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd"> 
<Header> 
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion> 
<MerchantIdentifier>Merchant id</MerchantIdentifier> 
</Header> 
<MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType> 
<Message> 
<MessageID>1</MessageID> 
<OrderFulfillment> 
<MerchantOrderID>AmazonOrderId</MerchantOrderID> 
<FulfillmentDate>2015-05-23T04:57:09+00:00</FulfillmentDate> 
<FulfillmentData> 
<CarrierCode>Fedex</CarrierCode> 
<ShipperTrackingNumber>78066505</ShipperTrackingNumber> 
</FulfillmentData> 
<Item> 
<MerchantOrderItemID>OrderItemId</MerchantOrderItemID> 
</Item> 
</OrderFulfillment> 
</Message> 
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

When I submit the feed getting response as We are unable to process the XML feed because one or more items are invalid. Please re-submit the feed. But both the order id and order item id is valid one.

In the sample [feed](http://amazonpayments.s3.amazonaws.com/documents/Managing_Orders_with_MWS_APIs_en_US.pdf) provided by amazon I can see `<MerchantFulfillmentID>1234567</MerchantFulfillmentID>` and `<MerchantFulfillmentItemID>1234567</MerchantFulfillmentItemID>` but where can I find these ids.

Answer (score 2):

As stated here [Selling on Amazon Guide to XML](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl._V324496426_.pdf):

> You can send your own unique order and item identifiers
>   (MerchantOrderID and MerchantOrderItemID) rather than Amazon's order
>   and item identifiers, if you established your own in the
>   OrderAcknowledgement feed.

**MerchantOrderID**:

> Optional seller supplied order ID. The first step is to establish the 
>   MerchantOrderID in the acknowledgem ent feed. Amazon will map the 
>   MerchantOrderID to the AmazonOrderID, and you can then use your own
>   order  ID (MerchantOrderID) for subsequent feeds relating to that
>   order. See the base XSD for the definition.

**MerchantFulfillmentID**:

> Seller supplied unique identifier for the shipment (not used by Amazon)

If you did not established your own ID´s in the OrderAcknowledgement feed, you can not use this fields in the Order Fulfillment feed.
Instead you have to speficy `AmazonOrderID` and `Item.AmazonOrderItemCode`. The `AmazonOrderItemCode` is an code for this specific product in this specific order. It has nothing todo with the famous ASIN or something.

Working example for an `_POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_` feed would like like:

```
<AmazonEnvelope>
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>M_TESTSHOP_1337</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OrderFulfillment>
      <AmazonOrderID>110-64133780-1337563</AmazonOrderID>
      <FulfillmentDate>2015-11-02T13:02:14</FulfillmentDate>
      <FulfillmentData>
        <CarrierName>DHL</CarrierName>
        <ShippingMethod>Paket</ShippingMethod>
        <ShipperTrackingNumber>1337</ShipperTrackingNumber>
      </FulfillmentData>
      <Item>
        <AmazonOrderItemCode>033521337643</AmazonOrderItemCode>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      </Item>
    </OrderFulfillment>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```